# Error when I try to exec date

Tags: perl

I was running this perl script (part of an open source project, not written by me) and it died on me. Below is the relevant part of the code:

```
$enddate = `date`;
```

The error I received:

```
Can't exec "date".
```

Is it a problem with the perl version? or the shell?

Comment: which environment are you using? System? And do you really need to execute a external command to get the date?

Comment: Don't you get an error message after the `Can't exec "date"`? What version of perl is it? What are your PATH, SHELL, and any other relevant environment variables? Can you run `date` from a shell using the same environment?

Comment: `$ENV{'PATH'}` will show you where it is looking for the `date` command.

Comment: @Jens, That can't be. No shell was used.

Comment: @jcaron, `$ENV{SHELL}` isn't used, `$Config{sh}` (which is `/bin/sh` on unix systems) would be used if a shell was used, but no shell was used.

Comment: @ikegami backticks execute the command _with "/bin/sh" or its equivalent_, as perlop says. Not sure how it determines which shell it uses, though. Also the message is indeed not exactly 'Can't exec "date".', but rather 'Can't exec "date": ' followed by the error, on the perl version I tried, but this may be different on older versions of perl?

Comment: @jcaron, like single-arg system and exec, backticks don't invoke a shell if the command contain no shell meta characters but spaces (and maybe other whitespace chars). For example, `perl -E'print \`set\`; say $? == -1 ? $! : $?;'`

Comment: @jcaron, But you're [right](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/0ab152a1d10861997fe3e1b985cc92f142f4cec7:/doio.c#l1525) about "Can't exec". Deleted my comment, and added an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the current date/time then you don't need to shell out to the date command anyway.

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date_time = strftime('%F %T', localtime());
print "$date_time\n";
```

POSIX is a core module so if you have Perl you should have POSIX.  See the [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) man page for details of the date format string.

You haven't really given us enough information to diagnose the problem with running date in backticks.  If I was trying to diagnose it I'd probably use a tool like `strace` but that might not be available for your platform.

Answer (score 3):

When Perl is asked to execute a shell command (whether through `exec`, `system`, `readpipe`/`qx`/backticks or `open`), and that shell command contains no shell metacharacters other than whitespace characters, Perl will execute the command itself rather than invoking a shell.

If Perl is unable to execute the program and warnings are enabled, Perl emits a warning saying the program can't be executed, along with the reason why.

```
$ perl -we'`non-existent`'
Can't exec "non-existent": No such file or directory at -e line 1.
```

You seem to misstated the message you received. The part you left off is the reason `date` could not be executed. For example, "No such file or directory" would indicate the program was not found in your path.

---

In any case, there's really no need to execute `date`. The following is equivalent:

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $enddate = strftime('%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', localtime()) . "\n";
```